# Javascript to detect if Chrome is set as default browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there anything in the Chrome extension APIs to detect if Chrome is set as default browser ?

My extension has (among other things) a function that automatically closes a new tab if the URL contains a certain string. These tabs are opened by another program and need to be closed. However, these tabs only open in Chrome if it is set as default browser, otherwise they will open in Internet Explorer. I need to warn users they have to set Chrome as default browser for this part of the extension to be useful, unless it is already set in which case the warning shouldn't display.

Comment: How that another programs opens these urls?

Comment: If your application depends on Chrome, why don't you detect the location of the Chrome browser and open the URL directly in Chrome?

Comment: @RobW: I don't think the user has an application, they have developed a Chrome Extension. This extension is designed to effectively block certain URL's from being opened. Now obviously because it's a Chrome extension it can only do it's job for web pages that are opened in Chrome. So for example, if a 3rd party application (or anything else) opens a web page it would generally open it in the machines default browser, which is out of the control of the OP. The OP wants to try and detect is Chrome is the default browser in order to provide a warning to the user.

Comment: Good job musefan for figuring it out :) I work in a call center. The tabs are used by an incident manager program, to open an incident with a certain number or simply a new incident. The order management system, a different program, uses these URLs to communicate with the incident manager. Once the latter has detected a tab with the URL in it, it opens the incident and the tab no longer has any use.

Comment: Having had a quick search through the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) I can't see anything that looks like it might help you. You may want to take a more in-depth look yourself, but I would say you may struggle to find a solution to this one

Comment: Other solutions might be: 1. If you have control over the application code that opens the tabs, change the code to force open in Chrome (as suggested by RobW) 2. If your users are on a network domain, you could use Windows Group Policy to enforce Chrome to be the default browser (see your IT guy about that if you have one)

Comment: Those were all very good suggestions, however they can't be applied. I guess I'll have to convince each user to set Chrome as default browser individually. Thanks anyway!